# random image in android

Tags: java, android

I have Images in drawable and I shuffle these images But I want that  ***R.drawable.a*** this image come 5 time and  **this  *R.drawable.b*** come 10 time but in my code image come again and again.

My question is that I want that image a **R.drawable.a**  come 5 time after that image **R.drawable.a** remove from list and other images come on shuffling all images .
But in mean time image a **R.drawable.a**  come n time

```
public void addNewImageToScreen() {
    //array of all drawable id's
    int pics[] = { R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b, R.drawable.c, ...etc...};
    Random rand = new Random();
    int pos = rand.nextInt(pics.length);
    addNewImageToScreen(pics[pos]);
}
```

Can Anybody help me how this is possible?

Comment: your code have no such lines which reflects what you are trying to do.
its a code for simple image movement.

Comment: So... you want to show all images sequentially, 1 at a time? Or do you want to show A and B in a 1:2 ratio? Context please.

Comment: I want to show image a and image b in 1:2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this code i think it will help you but i am not sure in my case it works fine

Random random = new Random( System.currentTimeMillis() );
List<Integer> generated = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < imageViews.length; i++) {

    int v = imageViews[i];
    int next = random.nextInt( 15 ) + 1;
    if ( !generated.contains( next ) ) {
        generated.add( next );
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById( v );
        iv.setImageResource( images[next] );
    }
    else {
        i--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the one you have shown earlier

```
 addNewImageToScreen(pics[pos]);

int arraySize=pics.length;
pics[pos] = pics[--arraySize];
```

Edit:
or use this logic

```
ArrayList picsarr=Arrays.asList(pics);
for(int i=0;i<picsarr.size;i++)
{
Collections.shuffle(picsarr);
 addNewImageToScreen(picsarr.get[i]);
picsarr.remove(i);
}
```

Comment: do you set pics[pos]=pics[--arraySize] ?

Comment: I use Same code as it is but not work 

pics[pos] = pics[--arraySize];

Comment: List<int[]> picsarr=Arrays.asList(pics);
  for(int i=0;i<picsarr.size();i++)
  {
  Collections.shuffle(picsarr);
I use this one because you write your code have error

   addNewImageToScreen(picsarr.get(0)[i]);
  picsarr.remove(i);
  }

Answer (score 1):

After some discussion with this fella it seems that this is what he wants:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> mDrawableIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        private void populateList() {
                mDrawableIds.add(R.drawable.a);
                mDrawableIds.add(R.drawable.b);
                mDrawableIds.add(R.drawable.c);
        }

private int returnImageResource(int buttonClickCount) {
        int imageResource = -1;

        switch (buttonClickCount) {
                case 1:
                        imageResource = mDrawableIds.get(0);
                        break;

                case 2:
                        imageResource = mDrawableIds.get((int) (Math.random() * mDrawableIds.size()));
                        break;

                case 3:
                        imageResource = mDrawableIds.get(1);
                        break;

                        // more cases here

                case 10:
                        imageResource = mDrawableIds.get((int) (Math.random() * mDrawableIds.size()));
                        mDrawableIds.remove(0);
                        break;
                }

        return imageResource;
    }
```

I left out some code but this should get you started. What you lacked was an ArrayList which you can remove entries from dynamically.